# Managed Package: Field History Not Reflecting After Installation/Upgrade

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api, metadata, history-tracking, field-history

For my managed package I am trying to enable tracking history for my managed object field.
I can see it in the source and build is also successful. But these changes are not reflecting, when my package is installed or updated in a subscriber org.

`<enableHistory>true</enableHistory>` This is set on the object xml file
`<trackHistory>true</trackHistory>` This is set on the field xml file

Am i missing anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation

*Field History Tracking is supported on custom objects in managed packages. However, if the package developer updates the packaged field history settings, those settings aren’t updated during package upgrades.*

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tracking_field_history_for_custom_objects.htm&type=5